# How to create certain number of JSON object using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json

I have this JSON object like below.

```
$scope.members = 
[{
  id: "member_0",
  json: {
    name: $cookieStore.get("member_0_name"),
    class: $cookieStore.get("member_0_class"),
    items: {
      fooItem: $cookieStore.get("member_0_items_fooItem")
    }
  }
},
{
  id: "member_1",
  json: {
    name: $cookieStore.get("member_1_name"),
    class: $cookieStore.get("member_1_class"),
    items: {
      fooItem: $cookieStore.get("member_1_items_fooItem")
    }
  }
}];
```

Now, I would like to improve the code so the certain number of JSON object can be created with the given number. I expect the code look would like below in pseudo but was unable to work it out.

```
var num_of_members = 5;

for (var i = 0; i < num_of_members; i++) {
  $scope.members = 
  [{
    id: "member_"+[i],
    json: {
      name: $cookieStore.get("member_"+[i]+"_name"),
      class: $cookieStore.get("member_"+[i]+"_class"),
      items: {
        fooItem: $cookieStore.get("member_"+[i]+"_items_fooItem")
      }
    }
  }];
}
```

Comment: whats the question? you posted the answer also.

Comment: @StarkButtowski The code below is only psudo, it is not working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this code will helps you:

```
var num_of_members = 5;
$scope.members = [];

for (var i = 0; i < num_of_members; i++) {
  var member = {
    id: "member_"+[i],
    json: {
      name: $cookieStore.get("member_"+[i]+"name"),
      class: $cookieStore.get("member_"+[i]+"class"),
      items: {
        fooItem: $cookieStore.get("member_"+[i]+"_items_fooItem")
      }
    }
  };
  $scope.members.push(member); 
}
```

Just create a new member for each id and push it into the array of members.